# Email sent from my iCloud email has started going to everyone’s Junk

Tags: icloud, email

I have a *username*@me.com email address that I've had since around 2011. All of a sudden, about two weeks ago, I've stopped getting replies from people.

Turns out that my emails—including responses to an already-ongoing thread—are ending up in people’s SPAM and Junk folders.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it? It's a huge problem.

Comment: If no one has a broad answer, could you edit this to narrow down the situation to a specific email processor? If you send one email with a subject, body and real human typing / no attachements, will it deliver to gmail or to me.com? You'll want to narrow down one specific web client that filters your mail to know what's happening.

Comment: Hi bmike, I can’t reproduce this on my own computer, sending to either Gmail or Google Apps or iCloud addresses.

Comment: So - how many people are seeing your messages not being delivered? What domains are they using?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing **you** can do, except use a different email address.

What happened, most likely, is that some nitwit spammed from his/her `me.com` address (or spoofed it), and one of the commonly used spam blacklists added the entire domain. The other people will need to catch this and add your email to their personal whitelist, the details of which will depend entirely on their email provider and/or email software (depending on which one's actually doing the filtering).

Comment: Highly unlikely me.com would be on any RBL - I would bet there are many things the OP can do like triage things with specific messages to specific providers and dig into what headers and what delivery patterns can be established. I could see one IP getting blacklisted for a very short time, but all your outgoing mail won't send from one of me.com's SMTP servers as they are load balanced. See http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3ame.com&run=toolpage

Comment: When my email was with Spamcop.net, blacklists were done on a domain name level as well as an IP level.

Comment: Yup - I linked to domain name checks. they are used for smaller domains - but rarely if ever for one that sends as much mail as me.com. (Hence the _highly unlikely_ part of my comment). Also, if the OP is sending a large volume of mail, the blocks might be legitimate. It's hard to tell without seeing their mail logs / mail volume and mail content.